# Supplying small and large floating point values to moodlepackage

Tags: parameters, moodle

I am using the "moodle" package to create Moodle XML quizzes via Latex. Generally it works pretty well but I am having problems. If you are unfamiliar with the package, I can use environment numerical to create  numerical answer like so:

```
\begin{numerical}
What is 2+2?
\item[tolerance=0.5] 4
\end{numerical}
```

This all works nicely, the package generates a PDF and also an XML file which can be uploaded to my Moodle site. But I have a problem if I am using values with scientific notation e.g.

```
\begin{numerical}
What is the charge on an electron?
\item[tolerance=1e-20] 1.602e-19
\end{numerical}
```

In this case it complains that the "e" is an illegal unit of measure and it used 'pt' instead.
I have not been able to get much luck searching, I don't think this is a widely used package or that it is in active development. Is this likely to be a package problem or is there a particular format for entering scientific notation numbers for latex parameters like this? Is that even possible!? I have tried both upper and lowercase 'e'

Answer (score 0):

The `moodle` package tries to determine whether the tolerance is set to 0 in order to display a `$\pm$ (tolerance)` in the PDF. For this, the package because it internally relies on TeX's dimensions

You can solve the problem by removing this test. In the preamble, after loading the `moodle` package, add the following code:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\moodle@print@numerical@answer@int@int#1\@rdelim{%
  \edef\moodle@numericalprint@tolerance{\noexpand\pm\moodle@tolerance}%
  \ifx\moodle@fraction\@hundred
    \item $#1\moodle@numericalprint@tolerance\quad\checkmark$%
  \else
    \item $#1\moodle@numericalprint@tolerance$\quad (\moodle@fraction\%)%
  \fi
}%
\def\moodle@print@clozenumerical@answer@int@int#1\@rdelim{%
  \ifx\moodle@fraction\@hundred
    \def\moodle@clozenumericalprint@fraction{$\checkmark$}%
  \else
    \edef\moodle@clozenumericalprint@fraction{(\moodle@fraction\%)}%
  \fi
    \edef\moodle@clozenumericalprint@tolerance{\noexpand\pm\moodle@tolerance}%
  \xdef\moodle@clozenumericalprint@line{$#1\moodle@clozenumericalprint@tolerance$
   & \moodle@clozenumericalprint@fraction}%
  \xa\g@addto@macro\xa\cloze@numerical@table@text\xa{\moodle@clozenumericalprint@line
   \\}%
}%
\makeatother
```

both compilation and Moodle import will be successful.